# Formatting Grouped Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I'm reading the following tutorial on group by, https://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_apply_operations_to_groups.html.

After the group by outlined below, how can I convert to a data frame that simply has **regiment, 1st, 2nd** as its columns?

[image: Grouped Dataframe]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your trying to remove that company from dataframe so use

```
df.columns.name = ''
```

In case you want to reset the index then use

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

Output :

```
ndf = df['preTestScore'].groupby([df['regiment'], df['company']]).mean().unstack()
ndf.columns.name = ''
```

```
            1st   2nd
regiment              
Dragoons     3.5  27.5
Nighthawks  14.0  16.5
Scouts       2.5   2.5
```

**`To have dataframe simply has regiment, 1st, 2nd as its columns`**

```
ndf = ndf.reset_index()
```

```
     regiment   1st   2nd
0    Dragoons   3.5  27.5
1  Nighthawks  14.0  16.5
2      Scouts   2.5   2.5
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Bharath, this works perfect. Just one question, what does `ndf.columns.name = ''` do?

Comment: If you check `df.columns` there will be an attribute called `name` that is what you are seeing in your dataframe. If you set that to an empty string it will make it dissappear.

Answer (score 0):

By using `rename_axis`

```
df.rename_axis(None,1)
```